How to use React on Rails with GraphQL SSR?
is it possible to use React on Rails to server-side render react component with GraphQL?
In react components I have GraphQL Apollo request, and there is a way to collect data needed for the components. The problem here is that the function returns Promise. React on rails (the same as execjs and mini_racer) doesn't support promises and setTimeout.
I've found another tool node-runner which has promises support. In fact it works and it allows me to ssr my react components in .erb files, but I am interested if there some ready-to-go solution.
Context:
I have a rails application which uses .erb files and I need to migrate the frontend part to nextjs. My plan is to start creating react components which can load data on their own, without bypassing data via props from rails. I can't use just client rendering, because of SEO. So eventually I will have react components that can operate data on their own and are incapsulated - it will be easier to insert them in nextjs application as-is.

There can be rails view that renders react component that fetches data with rest or graphql request, there can be separate frontend that fetches data with rest or graphql request

But what tool I should use? execjs and mini racer doesn't support promises, but in order to make apollo to gather queries data for ssr - promise support is needed.
p.s. React components must make requests, not rails
